# ¿Cómo puedo modificar valores de un data frame si cumple características de otro data frame?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-dplyr

Tengo el siguiente Data Frame

```
 coches<- data.frame(autos=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99), color=c(1,1,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,4,2,3,1,2,4,3,2,1,4,2,1,4,1,2,3,3,2,1,4,1,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,4,1,2,1,1,4,1,2,3,3,3,2,1,4,1,2,3,2,1,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,2,1,4,4,1,2,3,2,1,2,1,4,3,3,2,1,2,3,2,1,4,1,2,2,1,4,1,2,3,2,1,4), llantas=c(1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,22,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1))
```

Cómo podrán ver, en la variable color y llantas hay numeros. Y en los siguientes data frames, están los significados de las variable color y llantas

```
caracter<- data.frame(color=c("rojo", "azul", "verde", "blanco"))
llantas<- data.frame(llanta=c("si", "no"))
```

Lo que quiero, es modificar los números de las variables color y llantas del primer data frame, y que aparezcan en su lugar los significados de los numeros de los otros data frames.

Es decir, enlazar los data frames para que condicionen a las variables del primer data frame

y que quede algo así

```
coches2<- data.frame(autos=c(1,2,3), color=c("rojo", "rojo", "blanco", "verde"), llantas=c("si", "no", "si", "si"))
```

¡Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes en un `data.frame` son índice que apuntan a valores en otro `data.frame`, por lo que lo más simple es hacer algo así:

```
coches2 <- coches
coches2$llantas <- llantas$llanta[coches2$llantas]
coches2$color <- caracter$color[coches2$color]

head(coches2,4)

  autos  color llantas
1     1   rojo      si
2     2   rojo      no
3     3 blanco      si
4     4  verde      si
```

Comment: Hola Patricio, muchas gracias por tu ayuda. SIn embargo, tengo otra duda, ¿cómo le puedo decir a R que identifique por números a los colores? Por ejemplo, que verde sea 1, azul 4, rojo 3 y blanco 2, muchas gracias

Comment: Si transformas la columna en un `factor` puedes tratar los valores como numéricos: `as.numeric(factor(caracter$color))`